# Rails panel log window not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-chrome-extension

I have installed [Rails Panel](https://github.com/dejan/rails_panel) chrome extension, and the meta_request gem and it is mostly working. When I look at Rails panel in the developer tools, and click on different pages, I can see useful information in the Breakdown, Params, Activerecord etc tabs. It looks really great, but the Log tab is totally empty. I expected the actual log entries here, so what is going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that the Log tab only displays messages issued via `Rails.logger` commands such as `Rails.logger.info`.  Now I am used to it, this seems great, I am going to make much more use of the `Rails.logger` messages as it makes them much easier to see.

I am still interested in whether there is a setting to display all log messages.